# Where did Anya live before she moved in with Xander?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

In Buffy the Vampire Slayer, Anya joins the scoobies, and she dates Xander, but doesn't move in with him for a year or so.

There is one scene in which she answers the phone "at home" wearing $500 of 
mid-80's negligee. The room is Victorian and thoroughly home-decor-ed-- what the heck? She's unemployed; where was she living?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anya owned (or leased?) a [studio apartment in Sunnydale](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Anya_Jenkin%27s_apartment). There's zero indication how she came by it, but we can reasonably assume that it was created magically as part of her Anya Emerson persona.

We see it in [several episodes](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=inurl%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.buffyworld.com%2F%20%22Anya%27s%20apartment%22&oq=inurl%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.buffyworld.com%2F%20%22Anya%27s%20apartment%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.10422j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). The episode script for The Replacement describes it as below;

> **INT. ANYA'S APARTMENT - THE SAME TIME - NIGHT**
>
> Only a tiny glimpse of Anya's apartment, a corner with a short cabinet
> with an answering machine on it, and a few ancient Eastern ornaments
> on the wall. Anya stands next to the answering machine, listening as
> Xander leaves the message.
>
> <sub><sup>[Buffy: The Replacement](http://www.buffyworld.com/buffy/scripts/081_scri.html)</sup></sub>

[image]

And we see it again in [Buffy: Selfless](http://www.buffyworld.com/buffy/scripts/127_scri.html)

> INT. ANYA'S APARTMENT - DAY
>
> Anya and HALLIE are sitting on the couch. Anya has changed out of her
> bloodstained clothes.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Buffy: Selfless](http://www.buffyworld.com/buffy/scripts/127_scri.html)</sup></sub>

You may find it interesting that whenever the script talks about her apartment, the script specifically calls for the set designers not to make up a full set, just corners and edges.

Comment: Is that picture from a scene in The Replacement? It looks kind of like Anya from Selfless.

Comment: This must be the script for the scene I was describing. Your first link's text is garbled, and doesn't seem to specify where she was before cohabiting. It seems that the writers were being deliberately vague/tricky.

Comment: Are the scripts on that site transcribed from the show, or are they from the original scripts? If the former, then it doesn't clear up anything, and if it's the latter, then there is literally no answer to the question. My theory is, she's crashing with a demon "friend" in a hell dimension. :)

Comment: @Neal - These appear to be transcribed from the original scripts. The site also has "raw" transcripts taken from the episodes themselves. There's (periodically) differences between one and the other

Comment: @Neal - If you're after knowing where she lived when she was a vengeance demon, I'd assume she was crashing at D'Hoffryn's place.

Comment: Well, when you're a vengeance demon, you sleep where you like! It was the nightie in that top pic that set me off: *what* is she wearing? Why would she even have that? Where is she anyway? How did she get the phone hooked up? I can hear the writers talking about it: "HAH! Wouldn't they like to know." Later, she had a job, so, no mystery there. She never seemed homeless. Amoral, clueless, and tactless, but well-kept. :)

Comment: And zowie, you encyclopedic Buffy person, what an answer!

Comment: The bigger mystery, why didn't Xander sleep at her apartment rather than his parent's basement???

Comment: @MichaelLevy - Because that would require them making an additional set.